# Create new element by jQuery each time ajax is trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am struggling with the idea of, adding a fresh new elements to DOM for each time I triggered an AJAX call by jQuery.

The code below refresh the text everytime I triggered the AJAX call, I want it to add whole new element instead of refreshing.

BTW here is the code I have written.

```
function successAJAX(response){
        response = $.parseJSON(response);
        var priceHTML = document.createElement('p');
        priceHTML.innerText= "foo";
        $("#priceContainer").append(priceHTML);
    }
function makeAjaxRequest() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/ajax.php",
                data: obj,
                type: "post",
                success: successAJAX
            });//end ajax
        };//end makeRequest

        $button.on("submit",makeAjaxRequest());
```

The current situation is I can successfully add a new html element after I press submit button.

But I am not satisfied with this, I want to add one more new html element for each time I press the submit button.

For example, I can only append 1 element of html on the DOM now when I press the submit button(trigger ajax function) 100 times.

**My question is how can I append 100 elements of html on the DOM if I press the submit button(triggering ajax function) 100 times.**

Comment: You need to work on your explanation. I cannot figure out what you want to do from the current wording :( perhaps an example of what you expect or show the rest of the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function successAJAX(response){
    response = $.parseJSON(response);
    var priceHTML = document.createElement('p');
    priceHTML.innerText= "foo";
    $("#priceContainer").append(priceHTML);
}
```

First of all, what is that `response = $.parseJSON(response);` line doing there if you're not even using `response` in that function?

Secondly, we'd have to see the function that executes your AJAX to see what's going wrong, because there seems to be not so much wrong with your code.

By the way, you can also create your `priceHTML` var by using

```
var priceHTML = $('<p>'); 
priceHTML.html('foo');`
```

(since you're using jQuery).

Comment: I have edit my question, hope I can now clarify my question now.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,

```
var priceHTML = document.createElement('p');
priceHTML.innerHTML= "foo";
$("#priceContainer").append(priceHTML);
```

Comment: do you mean just cut the ajax function out and everything is solved?